# AWS IoT Rule engine not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot

Somehow none of the AWS IoT Rule  are working for me.
I published to topic, and sent SNS (as per example). 
SELECT * FROM 'acme/temp'

All policy and trust policy are correct , yet it does not fire rule.
Sad part is log level is DEBUG configured yet cloud watch shows only INFO and no info to know why rules not fired.

Trust policy

```
{
    "Version":"2012-10-17",
    "Statement":[{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": "iot.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }]
```

Role Policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "sns:Publish",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:643170122694:snstopic"
    }
}
```

Pl suggest how to troubleshoot.

I am using MQTT client inside AWS console to publish message to topic. If I subscribe then I get messages. I put my rule configuration here forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=741034&tstart=0 Can you think of any ways I can troubleshoot .. No matter what rule I write and what action I defined .. it does not fire Iot rule engine. I am using us east 1 region.

Comment: Not really an answer but just to make sure your rule SQL syntax is working; add a second action that is a "Republish a message to an AWS IoT topic" action. Just copy the data to another topic. Now if the rule fires, it should copy your message to that topic. If you dont see the copy, the rule syntax is incorrect.

Comment: @Mahesh: Same issue. Did you figure this out?